# Exporting dat in 3 column format

Tags: export

I have data like the following

dat = {{{0, 0, 311.429}, {0, 1, 0.0154873}}, {{1, 0, 0.0483966}, {1, 1, 
   0.0154212}}, {{2, 0, 0.0702652}, {2, 1, 0.0152236}}}

I want the data to be exported in text file in the following 3 column format

```
0  0   311.429
0  1   0.0154873
1  0   0.0483966
1  1   0.0154212
2  0   0.0702652
2  1   0.0152236
```

Export["taba.txt", Flatten /@dat, "Table"]

But I did not get my desired format. How can I get my desired format?

Comment: "I did not get my desired format." - can you explain why the `taba.txt` produced by `Export[]` is not in a suitable format?

Comment: 'taba.txt'' is the filename where I want to export the data.

Comment: That is clear. So, when you opened `taba.txt`, why was it not in your desired format?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the file format looking for in your prolemstatement.

```
dat = {{{0, 0, 311.429}, {0, 1, 0.0154873}}, {{1, 0, 0.0483966}, {1, 
    1,  0.0154212}}, {{2, 0, 0.0702652}, {2, 1, 0.0152236}}}

dat1 = FlattenAt[dat, -1]

FlattenAt[dat1, 2]

FlattenAt[%, 1]

TableForm[{{0, 0, 311.429}, {0, 1, 0.0154873}, {1, 0, 0.0483966}, {1, 
   1, 0.0154212}, {2, 0, 0.0702652}, {2, 1, 0.0152236}}]

Export["taba.txt", %, "Table"]

SystemOpen["taba.txt"]
```

**UPDATE:**

But you may simply write

```
dat = {{{0, 0, 311.429}, {0, 1, 0.0154873}}, {{1, 0, 0.0483966}, {1, 
    1, 0.0154212}}, {{2, 0, 0.0702652}, {2, 1, 0.0152236}}}
Flatten[dat, 1]
Export["taba.txt", %, "Table"]
SystemOpen["taba.txt"]
```

For the second option , please give credit to @J. M. is computer-less

Comment: Why not just `Flatten[dat, 1]`?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less  You are very correct. My answer just give a broader sight of the use of these functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Methods are working perfectly